# How would I traverse between these two arrayLists with a value-key relationship (Java)?

Tags: dictionary

Let's say, for example, I have two arrayLists. One has strings in the form of:

```
[a, b, a, a, c, a, d, b, d, b]
```

The other has integers in the form of:

```
[1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 2, 5, 1]
```

In this case, "a" has/maps to values 1, 2, 3, and 5 (because "a" is at index 0, 2, 3, 5 in arrayList 1, and the values at index 0, 2, 3, 5 in arrayList 2 are 1, 2, 3, and 5). "b" has values 4, 2, and 1. "c" has value 5. "d" has values 6 and 5.

Now I want to create a Map from these two arrayLists in the form of:

```
[(a, 11), (b, 7), (c, 5), (d, 11)]
```

where the value each string key is matched with is the sum of all its corresponding values in arrayList 2.

Any pointers on an efficient way to go about implementing this in Java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of operation is, abstractly, "zipping". The [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) of Java 8 works great here.

```
Map<String, Integer> m = IntStream.range(0, stringList.size()) // indices
    .boxed() // Stream<Integer>
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        stringList::get, // keyMapper
        intList::get, // valueMapper
        (x, y) -> x + y // mergeFunction for values when they have the same key
    ));
```

This code assumes that `intList` is the same size as, or longer than `stringList`. If `intList` can be shorter and you want to map the missing values to 0, you can modifiy the valueMapper from a method reference to a lambda.

Comment: Thank you! What about if I want to deal with String, Double instead of String, Integer? Would I still use IntStream?

Comment: The `IntStream` is the indices of the lists. Regardless of the types of values, an index of a list is an `int`.